# Could't update composer in ubuntu yii2 project

Tags: composer-php, ubuntu-16.04, yii2-advanced-app

When I run command update composer then it shows error as like as below. I install php7.xml file php mbstring but it shows this. When I run php version command it shows 7.0.25. Please help me to solve this issue.

```
   Problem 1
- codeception/base 2.3.7 requires phpunit/phpunit >=4.8.28 <5.0.0 || >=5.6.3 <7.0 -> satisfiable by phpunit/phpunit[4.8.28, 4.8.29, 4.8.30, 4.8.31, 4.8.32, 4.8.33, 4.8.34, 4.8.35, 4.8.36, 5.6.3, 5.6.4, 5.6.5, 5.6.6, 5.6.7, 5.6.8, 5.7.0, 5.7.1, 5.7.10, 5.7.11, 5.7.12, 5.7.13, 5.7.14, 5.7.15, 5.7.16, 5.7.17, 5.7.18, 5.7.19, 5.7.2, 5.7.20, 5.7.21, 5.7.22, 5.7.23, 5.7.24, 5.7.25, 5.7.26, 5.7.27, 5.7.3, 5.7.4, 5.7.5, 5.7.6, 5.7.7, 5.7.8, 5.7.9, 6.0.0, 6.0.1, 6.0.10, 6.0.11, 6.0.12, 6.0.13, 6.0.2, 6.0.3, 6.0.4, 6.0.5, 6.0.6, 6.0.7, 6.0.8, 6.0.9, 6.1.0, 6.1.1, 6.1.2, 6.1.3, 6.1.4, 6.2.0, 6.2.1, 6.2.2, 6.2.3, 6.2.4, 6.3.0, 6.3.1, 6.4.0, 6.4.1, 6.4.2, 6.4.3, 6.4.4, 6.5.0, 6.5.1, 6.5.2, 6.5.3, 6.5.4, 6.5.5, 6.5.6].

- codeception/base 2.2.8 requires phpunit/phpunit >4.8.20 <6.0 -> satisfiable by phpunit/phpunit[4.8.21, 4.8.22, 4.8.23, 4.8.24, 4.8.25, 4.8.26, 4.8.27, 4.8.28, 4.8.29, 4.8.30, 4.8.31, 4.8.32, 4.8.33, 4.8.34, 4.8.35, 4.8.36, 5.0.0, 5.0.1, 5.0.10, 5.0.2, 5.0.3, 5.0.4, 5.0.5, 5.0.6, 5.0.7, 5.0.8, 5.0.9, 5.1.0, 5.1.1, 5.1.2, 5.1.3, 5.1.4, 5.1.5, 5.1.6, 5.1.7, 5.2.0, 5.2.1, 5.2.10, 5.2.11, 5.2.12, 5.2.2, 5.2.3, 5.2.4, 5.2.5, 5.2.6, 5.2.7, 5.2.8, 5.2.9, 5.3.0, 5.3.1, 5.3.2, 5.3.3, 5.3.4, 5.3.5, 5.4.0, 5.4.1, 5.4.2, 5.4.3, 5.4.4, 5.4.5, 5.4.6, 5.4.7, 5.4.8, 5.5.0, 5.5.1, 5.5.2, 5.5.3, 5.5.4, 5.5.5, 5.5.6, 5.5.7, 5.6.0, 5.6.1, 5.6.2, 5.6.3, 5.6.4, 5.6.5, 5.6.6, 5.6.7, 5.6.8, 5.7.0, 5.7.1, 5.7.10, 5.7.11, 5.7.12, 5.7.13, 5.7.14, 5.7.15, 5.7.16, 5.7.17, 5.7.18, 5.7.19, 5.7.2, 5.7.20, 5.7.21, 5.7.22, 5.7.23, 5.7.24, 5.7.25, 5.7.26, 5.7.27, 5.7.3, 5.7.4, 5.7.5, 5.7.6, 5.7.7, 5.7.8, 5.7.9].
- codeception/base 2.2.9 requires phpunit/phpunit >4.8.20 <6.0 -> satisfiable by phpunit/phpunit[4.8.21, 4.8.22, 4.8.23, 4.8.24, 4.8.25, 4.8.26, 4.8.27, 4.8.28, 4.8.29, 4.8.30, 4.8.31, 4.8.32, 4.8.33, 4.8.34, 4.8.35, 4.8.36, 5.0.0, 5.0.1, 5.0.10, 5.0.2, 5.0.3, 5.0.4, 5.0.5, 5.0.6, 5.0.7, 5.0.8, 5.0.9, 5.1.0, 5.1.1, 5.1.2, 5.1.3, 5.1.4, 5.1.5, 5.1.6, 5.1.7, 5.2.0, 5.2.1, 5.2.10, 5.2.11, 5.2.12, 5.2.2, 5.2.3, 5.2.4, 5.2.5, 5.2.6, 5.2.7, 5.2.8, 5.2.9, 5.3.0, 5.3.1, 5.3.2, 5.3.3, 5.3.4, 5.3.5, 5.4.0, 5.4.1, 5.4.2, 5.4.3, 5.4.4, 5.4.5, 5.4.6, 5.4.7, 5.4.8, 5.5.0, 5.5.1, 5.5.2, 5.5.3, 5.5.4, 5.5.5, 5.5.6, 5.5.7, 5.6.0, 5.6.1, 5.6.2, 5.6.3, 5.6.4, 5.6.5, 5.6.6, 5.6.7, 5.6.8, 5.7.0, 5.7.1, 5.7.10, 5.7.11, 5.7.12, 5.7.13, 5.7.14, 5.7.15, 5.7.16, 5.7.17, 5.7.18, 5.7.19, 5.7.2, 5.7.20, 5.7.21, 5.7.22, 5.7.23, 5.7.24, 5.7.25, 5.7.26, 5.7.27, 5.7.3, 5.7.4, 5.7.5, 5.7.6, 5.7.7, 5.7.8, 5.7.9].
- codeception/base 2.3.0 requires phpunit/phpunit >4.8.20 <6.0 -> satisfiable by phpunit/phpunit[4.8.21, 4.8.22, 4.8.23, 4.8.24, 4.8.25, 4.8.26, 4.8.27, 4.8.28, 4.8.29, 4.8.30, 4.8.31, 4.8.32, 4.8.33, 4.8.34, 4.8.35, 4.8.36, 5.0.0, 5.0.1, 5.0.10, 5.0.2, 5.0.3, 5.0.4, 5.0.5, 5.0.6, 5.0.7, 5.0.8, 5.0.9, 5.1.0, 5.1.1, 5.1.2, 5.1.3, 5.1.4, 5.1.5, 5.1.6, 5.1.7, 5.2.0, 5.2.1, 5.2.10, 5.2.11, 5.2.12, 5.2.2, 5.2.3, 5.2.4, 5.2.5, 5.2.6, 5.2.7, 5.2.8, 5.2.9, 5.3.0, 5.3.1, 5.3.2, 5.3.3, 5.3.4, 5.3.5, 5.4.0, 5.4.1, 5.4.2, 5.4.3, 5.4.4, 5.4.5, 5.4.6, 5.4.7, 5.4.8, 5.5.0, 5.5.1, 5.5.2, 5.5.3, 5.5.4, 5.5.5, 5.5.6, 5.5.7, 5.6.0, 5.6.1, 5.6.2, 5.6.3, 5.6.4, 5.6.5, 5.6.6, 5.6.7, 5.6.8, 5.7.0, 5.7.1, 5.7.10, 5.7.11, 5.7.12, 5.7.13, 5.7.14, 5.7.15, 5.7.16, 5.7.17, 5.7.18, 5.7.19, 5.7.2, 5.7.20, 5.7.21, 5.7.22, 5.7.23, 5.7.24, 5.7.25, 5.7.26, 5.7.27, 5.7.3, 5.7.4, 5.7.5, 5.7.6, 5.7.7, 5.7.8, 5.7.9].
- codeception/base 2.3.1 requires phpunit/phpunit >4.8.20 <7.0 -> satisfiable by phpunit/phpunit[4.8.21, 4.8.22, 4.8.23, 4.8.24, 4.8.25, 4.8.26, 4.8.27, 4.8.28, 4.8.29, 4.8.30, 4.8.31, 4.8.32, 4.8.33, 4.8.34, 4.8.35, 4.8.36, 5.0.0, 5.0.1, 5.0.10, 5.0.2, 5.0.3, 5.0.4, 5.0.5, 5.0.6, 5.0.7, 5.0.8, 5.0.9, 5.1.0, 5.1.1, 5.1.2, 5.1.3, 5.1.4, 5.1.5, 5.1.6, 5.1.7, 5.2.0, 5.2.1, 5.2.10, 5.2.11, 5.2.12, 5.2.2, 5.2.3, 5.2.4, 5.2.5, 5.2.6, 5.2.7, 5.2.8, 5.2.9, 5.3.0, 5.3.1, 5.3.2, 5.3.3, 5.3.4, 5.3.5, 5.4.0, 5.4.1, 5.4.2, 5.4.3, 5.4.4, 5.4.5, 5.4.6, 5.4.7, 5.4.8, 5.5.0, 5.5.1, 5.5.2, 5.5.3, 5.5.4, 5.5.5, 5.5.6, 5.5.7, 5.6.0, 5.6.1, 5.6.2, 5.6.3, 5.6.4, 5.6.5, 5.6.6, 5.6.7, 5.6.8, 5.7.0, 5.7.1, 5.7.10, 5.7.11, 5.7.12, 5.7.13, 5.7.14, 5.7.15, 5.7.16, 5.7.17, 5.7.18, 5.7.19, 5.7.2, 5.7.20, 5.7.21, 5.7.22, 5.7.23, 5.7.24, 5.7.25, 5.7.26, 5.7.27, 5.7.3, 5.7.4, 5.7.5, 5.7.6, 5.7.7, 5.7.8, 5.7.9, 6.0.0, 6.0.1, 6.0.10, 6.0.11, 6.0.12, 6.0.13, 6.0.2, 6.0.3, 6.0.4, 6.0.5, 6.0.6, 6.0.7, 6.0.8, 6.0.9, 6.1.0, 6.1.1, 6.1.2, 6.1.3, 6.1.4, 6.2.0, 6.2.1, 6.2.2, 6.2.3, 6.2.4, 6.3.0, 6.3.1, 6.4.0, 6.4.1, 6.4.2, 6.4.3, 6.4.4, 6.5.0, 6.5.1, 6.5.2, 6.5.3, 6.5.4, 6.5.5, 6.5.6].
- codeception/base 2.3.2 requires phpunit/phpunit >4.8.20 <7.0 -> satisfiable by phpunit/phpunit[4.8.21, 4.8.22, 4.8.23, 4.8.24, 4.8.25, 4.8.26, 4.8.27, 4.8.28, 4.8.29, 4.8.30, 4.8.31, 4.8.32, 4.8.33, 4.8.34, 4.8.35, 4.8.36, 5.0.0, 5.0.1, 5.0.10, 5.0.2, 5.0.3, 5.0.4, 5.0.5, 5.0.6, 5.0.7, 5.0.8, 5.0.9, 5.1.0, 5.1.1, 5.1.2, 5.1.3, 5.1.4, 5.1.5, 5.1.6, 5.1.7, 5.2.0, 5.2.1, 5.2.10, 5.2.11, 5.2.12, 5.2.2, 5.2.3, 5.2.4, 5.2.5, 5.2.6, 5.2.7, 5.2.8, 5.2.9, 5.3.0, 5.3.1, 5.3.2, 5.3.3, 5.3.4, 5.3.5, 5.4.0, 5.4.1, 5.4.2, 5.4.3, 5.4.4, 5.4.5, 5.4.6, 5.4.7, 5.4.8, 5.5.0, 5.5.1, 5.5.2, 5.5.3, 5.5.4, 5.5.5, 5.5.6, 5.5.7, 5.6.0, 5.6.1, 5.6.2, 5.6.3, 5.6.4, 5.6.5, 5.6.6, 5.6.7, 5.6.8, 5.7.0, 5.7.1, 5.7.10, 5.7.11, 5.7.12, 5.7.13, 5.7.14, 5.7.15, 5.7.16, 5.7.17, 5.7.18, 5.7.19, 5.7.2, 5.7.20, 5.7.21, 5.7.22, 5.7.23, 5.7.24, 5.7.25, 5.7.26, 5.7.27, 5.7.3, 5.7.4, 5.7.5, 5.7.6, 5.7.7, 5.7.8, 5.7.9, 6.0.0, 6.0.1, 6.0.10, 6.0.11, 6.0.12, 6.0.13, 6.0.2, 6.0.3, 6.0.4, 6.0.5, 6.0.6, 6.0.7, 6.0.8, 6.0.9, 6.1.0, 6.1.1, 6.1.2, 6.1.3, 6.1.4, 6.2.0, 6.2.1, 6.2.2, 6.2.3, 6.2.4, 6.3.0, 6.3.1, 6.4.0, 6.4.1, 6.4.2, 6.4.3, 6.4.4, 6.5.0, 6.5.1, 6.5.2, 6.5.3, 6.5.4, 6.5.5, 6.5.6].
- codeception/base 2.3.3 requires phpunit/phpunit >4.8.20 <7.0 -> satisfiable by phpunit/phpunit[4.8.21, 4.8.22, 4.8.23, 4.8.24, 4.8.25, 4.8.26, 4.8.27, 4.8.28, 4.8.29, 4.8.30, 4.8.31, 4.8.32, 4.8.33, 4.8.34, 4.8.35, 4.8.36, 5.0.0, 5.0.1, 5.0.10, 5.0.2, 5.0.3, 5.0.4, 5.0.5, 5.0.6, 5.0.7, 5.0.8, 5.0.9, 5.1.0, 5.1.1, 5.1.2, 5.1.3, 5.1.4, 5.1.5, 5.1.6, 5.1.7, 5.2.0, 5.2.1, 5.2.10, 5.2.11, 5.2.12, 5.2.2, 5.2.3, 5.2.4, 5.2.5, 5.2.6, 5.2.7, 5.2.8, 5.2.9, 5.3.0, 5.3.1, 5.3.2, 5.3.3, 5.3.4, 5.3.5, 5.4.0, 5.4.1, 5.4.2, 5.4.3, 5.4.4, 5.4.5, 5.4.6, 5.4.7, 5.4.8, 5.5.0, 5.5.1, 5.5.2, 5.5.3, 5.5.4, 5.5.5, 5.5.6, 5.5.7, 5.6.0, 5.6.1, 5.6.2, 5.6.3, 5.6.4, 5.6.5, 5.6.6, 5.6.7, 5.6.8, 5.7.0, 5.7.1, 5.7.10, 5.7.11, 5.7.12, 5.7.13, 5.7.14, 5.7.15, 5.7.16, 5.7.17, 5.7.18, 5.7.19, 5.7.2, 5.7.20, 5.7.21, 5.7.22, 5.7.23, 5.7.24, 5.7.25, 5.7.26, 5.7.27, 5.7.3, 5.7.4, 5.7.5, 5.7.6, 5.7.7, 5.7.8, 5.7.9, 6.0.0, 6.0.1, 6.0.10, 6.0.11, 6.0.12, 6.0.13, 6.0.2, 6.0.3, 6.0.4, 6.0.5, 6.0.6, 6.0.7, 6.0.8, 6.0.9, 6.1.0, 6.1.1, 6.1.2, 6.1.3, 6.1.4, 6.2.0, 6.2.1, 6.2.2, 6.2.3, 6.2.4, 6.3.0, 6.3.1, 6.4.0, 6.4.1, 6.4.2, 6.4.3, 6.4.4, 6.5.0, 6.5.1, 6.5.2, 6.5.3, 6.5.4, 6.5.5, 6.5.6].
- codeception/base 2.3.4 requires phpunit/phpunit >4.8.20 <7.0 -> satisfiable by phpunit/phpunit[4.8.21, 4.8.22, 4.8.23, 4.8.24, 4.8.25, 4.8.26, 4.8.27, 4.8.28, 4.8.29, 4.8.30, 4.8.31, 4.8.32, 4.8.33, 4.8.34, 4.8.35, 4.8.36, 5.0.0, 5.0.1, 5.0.10, 5.0.2, 5.0.3, 5.0.4, 5.0.5, 5.0.6, 5.0.7, 5.0.8, 5.0.9, 5.1.0, 5.1.1, 5.1.2, 5.1.3, 5.1.4, 5.1.5, 5.1.6, 5.1.7, 5.2.0, 5.2.1, 5.2.10, 5.2.11, 5.2.12, 5.2.2, 5.2.3, 5.2.4, 5.2.5, 5.2.6, 5.2.7, 5.2.8, 5.2.9, 5.3.0, 5.3.1, 5.3.2, 5.3.3, 5.3.4, 5.3.5, 5.4.0, 5.4.1, 5.4.2, 5.4.3, 5.4.4, 5.4.5, 5.4.6, 5.4.7, 5.4.8, 5.5.0, 5.5.1, 5.5.2, 5.5.3, 5.5.4, 5.5.5, 5.5.6, 5.5.7, 5.6.0, 5.6.1, 5.6.2, 5.6.3, 5.6.4, 5.6.5, 5.6.6, 5.6.7, 5.6.8, 5.7.0, 5.7.1, 5.7.10, 5.7.11, 5.7.12, 5.7.13, 5.7.14, 5.7.15, 5.7.16, 5.7.17, 5.7.18, 5.7.19, 5.7.2, 5.7.20, 5.7.21, 5.7.22, 5.7.23, 5.7.24, 5.7.25, 5.7.26, 5.7.27, 5.7.3, 5.7.4, 5.7.5, 5.7.6, 5.7.7, 5.7.8, 5.7.9, 6.0.0, 6.0.1, 6.0.10, 6.0.11, 6.0.12, 6.0.13, 6.0.2, 6.0.3, 6.0.4, 6.0.5, 6.0.6, 6.0.7, 6.0.8, 6.0.9, 6.1.0, 6.1.1, 6.1.2, 6.1.3, 6.1.4, 6.2.0, 6.2.1, 6.2.2, 6.2.3, 6.2.4, 6.3.0, 6.3.1, 6.4.0, 6.4.1, 6.4.2, 6.4.3, 6.4.4, 6.5.0, 6.5.1, 6.5.2, 6.5.3, 6.5.4, 6.5.5, 6.5.6].
- phpunit/phpunit 6.5.6 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
- phpunit/phpunit 6.5.5 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
```

Comment: you are possibly missing a php extension `php-xml`

Comment: I allready mention that also installed.

Comment: i've missed that, sorry. still are you sure that the command line php is the same as as the one used by the webserver and that dom\xml shows up if you run `php -i`